# Traveling Salesman Problem where not all cities need to be visited

Tags: optimization, terminology, data-analysis, discrete-optimization, operations-research

If there are a total of X possible cities to travel to, but our salesman only has to visit a fixed number of them Y<X, how do we choose the Y cities to travel to and the order? Has this problem been studied and/or does it have a formal name? Appreciate any references or real-world applications of this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, search for *optimal subtour problem*, *orienteering problem*, and *prize-collecting TSP*.  This problem appears as a subproblem in column-generation approaches to the vehicle routing problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I can finally satisfy the reviewers' comments with solid references.